# CVE-2020-5250 php vulnerability analysis

Tags: php, vulnerability, patching

I am exploring the [vulnerability](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/security/advisories/GHSA-mhfc-6rhg-fxp3) ([CVE-2020-5250](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2020-5250)) found in PrestaShop software versions <1.7.6.4. Could somebody explain how (with which method) was the program exactly exploitable? And why is the [patch provided](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/commit/a4a609b5064661f0b47ab5bc538e1a9cd3dd1069) adequate? Is this a common mistake made when developing software in php? Could not find any information on this topic and thought it would help other developers to learn from this mistake.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Without doing an in-depth analysis, it looks like a case of IDOR (Insecure Direct Object References). This means that the server does not properly enforce access controls; simply knowing a value (in this case, `id_address` or `id_customer`) is enough to gain access to the object. By changing these values in a form field, a user could manipulate other accounts that they should not have access to.

The patch seems logical; instead of trusting user-provided form input to determine which user the data belongs to, it now appears to check the user's session data, which cannot be forged by the user.